# How can Doxygen exclude a C++ class?

Tags: c++, doxygen

I want to exclude a class from documentation in Doxygen. Usually these classes are in files named the same, but there are many times when they are included inside other class definitions. This is mainly for classes starting with "_" or "Private".

How can I tell Doxygen to exclude a C++ class?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18):

You can use [the `\cond` tag](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdcond).  Before the class definition, add:

```
\cond HIDDEN_SYMBOLS
```

and after the class definition add:

```
\endcond
```

Unless you define `HIDDEN_SYMBOLS` in your doxyfile, the contents between the `\cond` and `\endcond` tags will not be documented.  You can replace `HIDDEN_SYMBOLS` with whatever you like.

Comment: Is there a way to do it in the sources without `\cond` and `\endcond`? Maybe something like `\nodoc` or `\nodoxygen` on the class? I did not see a command in the Doxygen manual under [Special Commands](https://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/commands.html), but I may have missed it.

Answer (score 12):

[EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS](http://www.doxygen.nl/config.html#cfg_exclude_symbols) may be my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using Doxygen GUI you can find multiple exclude options under

```
"expert > input"
```

You may find specially useful:

- Exclude symbols: Excludes everything containing a determined word regex like */word/*
- Exclude patterns: Excludes a determinated path regex like */folder/* or */some/file.cs*/