# Doxygen last enum member not documented

Tags: c++, c, enums, doxygen

I have an enum that uses member grouping to set the members values all at once in a group.

Here is the code :

```
/** MP format tags
 *
 * See the DC-007_E Specification.
 * 5.2.2.3  Table 3, page 13
 */
typedef enum
{
    /*MP Index IFD*/


    ///@{
    ///Mandatory
    MPTag_MPFVersion        = 0xB000,
    MPTag_NumberOfImages    = 0xB001,
    MPTag_MPEntry           = 0xB002,
    ///@}


    ///@{
    ///Optional
    //TODO : implement those tags
    MPTag_ImageUIDList      = 0xB003,
    MPTag_TotalFrames       = 0xB004,
    ///@}

    ///@{
    ///Individual image tags (attributes)
    MPTag_IndividualNum     = 0xb101,
    MPTag_PanOrientation    = 0xb201,
    MPTag_PanOverlapH       = 0xb202,
    MPTag_PanOverlapV       = 0xb203,
    MPTag_BaseViewpointNum  = 0xb204,
    MPTag_ConvergenceAngle  = 0xb205,
    MPTag_BaselineLength    = 0xb206,
    MPTag_VerticalDivergence= 0xb207,
    MPTag_AxisDistanceX     = 0xb208,
    MPTag_AxisDistanceY     = 0xb209,
    MPTag_AxisDistanceZ     = 0xb20a,
    MPTag_YawAngle          = 0xb20b,
    MPTag_PitchAngle        = 0xb20c,
    MPTag_RollAngle         = 0xb20d

    ///@}
}MPExt_MPTags;
```

But the last member of the enum (`MPTag_RollAngle`) isn't documented.

I set the `DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC` to `true`

You can see the html output [here](http://lectem.github.io/libmpo/mpo_8h.html#a026f15987e14cbf63c3a44f18d358602)

## Update :

The bug has been fixed :

- commit : [enter link description here](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/commit/50a329c056a2676608f30321a3207ff17ab20abb)
- bug tracker : [enter link description here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=746226)

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but did you try `MPTag_RollAngle         = 0xb20d,`? Note the postfixed comma, and yes it's legal syntax.

Comment: adding a comma does work, but I don't think it is a final solution. Would it mean it is a Doxygen bug ?

Comment: @Lectem: I'd say so, yes.

Comment: Looks to me a duplicate of bug_645165 (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=645165) and see given comment with this bug report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just add a trailing comma to that last `enum` element to get it auto documented:

```
typedef enum  {
    // ...
    MPTag_RollAngle = 0xb20d, // <<< add trailing comma
};
```

---

> *"adding a comma does work, but I don't think it is a final solution. Would it mean it is a Doxygen bug ?"*

Well, that could be that could be considered a bug of the doxygen parser of course.
But I personally prefer this style anyway (to be honest: I'm abusing that to make copying lines and editing easier, which should be considered a strongly discouraged behavior when writing code).

Comment: Approved since it's working and that there is probably no other solution. For future reference, the bug as been reported https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=746226

Comment: Not working here any more (Fedora 21 up to date). I wanted to *hide* the last member and with or without comma it's documented anyway.

Comment: @moorray May be it was fixed in your doxygen version meanwhile. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619577/how-can-doxygen-exclude-a-c-class) shows a technique how you can actually hide any elements from being documented.