# Is there a simpler way of making doxygen skip myclass than with @cond?

Tags: doxygen, documentation-generation

I want doxygen to skip one of my C++ classes - and I do not want to tell it to skip the class using files external to the code itself; it has to be inline doxygen markup.

I know I can do this with:

```
///@cond
struct Foo { ... }
///@endcond
```

but I really don't like:

1. That the word "code" does not intuitively come across as "not to be documented"
2. That you have an opening and closing command.

I would really have liked to have something like:

```
///@undocumented
struct Foo { ... }
```

is this doable achievable Doxygen (or some other way)?

Notes:

- A related question:

  [How can Doxygen exclude a C++ class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1619577/1593077)

Comment: In the header you mention \cond in the description \code, I assume you meant in the description also \cond. There is another way by using the standard #if constructs.

Comment: @albert: Yeah, sorry, mistype.